# Python AttributeError:'NoneType' object has no attribute getText

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, attributeerror

It´s my first time here!. I´m new with python and I´m getting error :"'NoneType' object has no attribute getText."
I´m working with the Requests and  BeautifulSoup libraries. It´s  about chess.com, a chess web, where all your data games can be downloaded. I'm learning about web scraping and data visualization, and the idea is to work with my info.  The code is:

```
text = page.text

b = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')

content = b.find('span', attrs={'class': re.compile("archive-games-game-time")})

content.getText().strip()
```

"massarov" is my username in the page. I dont´know what´s wrong. Could anyone help me please?????.

Comment: first of try `print(content)` and see what you get (thats for debugging). The reason probably is that what you were trying to find does not exist or it cant find it

Comment: The value returned by `b.find` is None.  You need to check for `if content is not None:` before trying to use `getText()`.  My guess is, your find did not find what you were looking for.

Comment: actually I may have understood. are you also logging in your account in that page?

Answer (score 0):

if you are logging in it may be better to use `session` as it keeps your cookies:

```
session = requests.Session()
session.post(post_link, data=yourdata)

data = session.get(link)
```

this will keep you logged in when you change url (go to a different page on website). so whenever there is need to keep cookies use `session`

Comment: Thanks for the answer Matiiss!, I did it in a similar way, but I still get the same error, is it ok ?:

`import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
s = requests.Session()
data = {"login":"massarov", "password":"******"}
url = "https://www.chess.com/login_and_go?returnUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.chess.com%2F"
r = s.post(url, data=data)
page = requests.get('https://www.chess.com/games/archive/massarov')
text = page.text
b = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')
import re
content = b.find('span', attrs={'class': re.compile("archive-games-game-time")})
content.getText().strip()`

Comment: @MaximilianoVazquez  Im pretty sure I stated clearly that you have to get data with session (in your case like this) `page = session.get('https://www.chess.com/games/archive/massarov')`

Comment: thanks!, but it´s not working.  here is the original post which i m using and it seems to be no need of using session/session.post,...

[link] (https://towardsdatascience.com/web-scraping-and-visualizing-chess-data-af75f8f92354))

Comment: @MaximilianoVazquez well in that case your script just cant find what you are asking it to find